# How to copy the value of a yform to an other field

Tags: javascript, sap-commerce-cloud, orbeon

In our (hybris) shop some products have a yform to summarize the parts of the product. Is there an easy way to copy the value of the sum field into an other field (automaticly) like the productquantity (no yForm)?
I guess I need javascript, but the id of the sumfield is generatad, so I don't know how to get the sum. Also my Javascript abilities are quite limited...

UPDATE:

To get the value I use this part of code:

```
copyYFormValueToProductQuantity : function() {
    var copyText = document.querySelector('input[id*="sum"]').value
    if (copyText > 0 && copyText != null)
        {
        //do stuff
        }
  console.log("Copied value: " + copyText)

},
```

But this line

```
document.querySelector('input[id*="sum"]').value
```

returns null. If I use it in the browserconsole, it also returns null. But after I inspected the element it works and returns the value I want to. So I guess I am missing some JS-basics here and the object isn't ready before?

Btw.: I call this function with a keydown-eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

This can most likely be done from the jsp files. There you have all the data that is needed, so you most likely need to only copy that field where you need it.

We can also help you more if you add some code examples here (what exactly is that yform?). If you struggle to find where in code is that specific yform created/added, it's always worth giving a try to search for the applied classes of the html (search the entire project and see what you find).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I updated my post. I got a working selector now, but there are still some issues.

Comment: Can you update the jsp files so you can give an ID to that element? then you can query the document using that id. It seems strange that after you inspect that specific element you get it to work, maybe it is not initialized at that point? Try modifying you query selector to be more general, it will also include other fields, but you can filter them later on. For example, query only for "input" and see if the array contains what you need. You can also paste the element (html) here so we can build a custom query together.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are saying that you want to copy the value of a yForm field named `sum` into a non-yForm field named `productquantity`, and you are asking specifically about how to access the value of a yForm field from JavaScript. If I understand this correctly, you can do so by calling the following JavaScript API:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("sum");
```

You can find more about this and other related API on [Client-side JavaScript API](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/core/client-side-javascript-api).